# Azure DevOps Pipeline Fails to Run Docker Task on Self-Hosted macOS Agent

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am encountering an issue with an Azure DevOps pipeline that fails to execute a Docker task on a self-hosted macOS agent. The agent is supposed to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile and push it to a registry, but it seems unable to communicate with the Docker daemon.

Here is the relevant part of the pipeline configuration:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'docker-connection'
    repository: 'enmareynoso/ids339-final'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
```

The Docker daemon is running correctly on my machine, and I can execute Docker commands manually with the user that runs the Azure DevOps agent. However, when the pipeline runs, it fails with the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I've verified that Docker Desktop is running, and the user has the necessary permissions to interact with Docker. Here's what the environment looks like when I run **`docker --version`** and inspect the Docker symlink:

```
Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
```

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  54 Nov 28  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
```

Despite trying all the solutions available on the internet,  the issue persists. I'm looking for suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Is your self-hosted agent on the same machine as Docker? If it is, please try to run the Docker commands directly in a command line task instead of using Docker task and check what's the result. 2. If they are on the different machines, please try to set up a self-hosted agent on the machine where you can run docker commands and use it to run the pipeline. Besides, you can try to check if the MS-hosted agent can run the pipeline successfully.

Comment: Can you add output from `cat /etc/docker/daemon.json` also check is file `/var/run/docker.sock` exists?